# Change array format in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 23
            [orgId] => 6
            [validity] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 5
            [orgId] => 2
            [validity] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 5
            [orgId] => 5
            [validity] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 7
            [orgId] => 4
            [validity] => 10
        )

)
```

and i want to show that like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 23
            [orgId] => 6
            [validity] => 20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 5
            [orgId] => 2
            [validity] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 5
            [orgId] => 5
            [validity] => 4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 7
            [orgId] => 4
            [validity] => 10
        )

)
```

To do that i used array_push & some other technique but fail.
can someone help me thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your example you want the elements to be re-indexed, and maintain their existing order.

Try using [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

> array_values() returns all the values
>   from the input array and indexes
>   numerically the array.

Answer (score 0):

yes array_values is the answer, you can go through this discussion too http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-17794.html